# Changing scale without changing dimensions

Tags: scale, dimensions

I am facing some troubles with the size of an end cap of the Array Modifier. I want to change solely the size of the cap to make it longer. It appears that I can influence the size of the end cap solely by scaling the object on which the Array Modifier acts. However, I don't want to change the size of that object anymore, thus my question: How can I solely change the scale of an object without changing its size or dimensions.

On the internet I just found the question for the other way around by applying the scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply scale the origin of the object.

1. Check *Tool > Transforms > Only Origins*
2. Scale your object (it won't visually change dimensions)
3. Done.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make the Scale input boxes in the Tools > Transform menu also scale only origins? Currently it seems this setting only affects scaling in the 3D viewport.

Comment: Hi :). No idea, but perhaps if you share your problem, somebody can offer an alternative :).

Answer (score 1):

It works for the simple cube, but I figured out how to do it with an armature that is connected to a mesh because sometimes things like this happen when you just scale and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>:

[image]

I accidentally found out that it works if you scale it and use *Scale to Deltas* instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>:

[image]

My goal was to change dimensions from Z=3.45 to Z=2.00 without changing 111 scale proportion. And it works just fine.